# Chrome security/permissions bar to allow webcam and audio

Tags: javascript, flash, security, google-chrome, webcam

I'm trying to show a graphic as a helper to the user to address the security bar that Chrome shows when trying to access webcam/microphone through flash. The user first addresses Flash's security panel but tends to forget the one Chrome dispatches.

After the user addresses the Flash security dialog to allow access, I would like to display a graphic to remind them to click allow on Chrome's security bar. The site is deployed through HTTPS so chrome will remember the user's selection. With that being said, I only want to show this graphic if Chrome's security bar is dispatched. I couldn't find any calls from Chrome to dispatch it's security bar so that I could listen for it via Javascript.

I was also thinking of looking into the user's media exceptions to see if my URL was there, but I fear that would be unacceptable.

Does anyone know how I can detect if that bar is showing?

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We finally found a workaround that I would like to share, the ActionScript Camera has a public property called [`currentFPS`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#currentFPS) which while the permission is pending will be constant and set to `0`(zero). We use that property to decide either or not we should display an user notification.